# IMediator mock return null from controller class in xUnit test

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-5, web-api-testing, mediatr

I have Web API Controller and trying to test end-point. I am using MediatR in controller class for method 'GetHandHeldByIMEI()' . I have used Setup (x => x.Send( new GetHandHeldByIMEI(imei) but in debugging the it return null; not sure what I am missing here?? refer as below

[image]

### Test Class

public class MyTestControllerTest
{
private readonly HandheldController sut;
private readonly Mock mediatorMoq;
private readonly Mock appAmbientStateMoq;

```
public HandheldControllerTest()
{
   mediatorMoq = new Mock<IMediator>();
   appAmbientStateMoq = new Mock<IAppAmbientState>();
   sut = new HandheldController(appAmbientStateMoq.Object, mediatorMoq.Object);
 }

 [Fact]
 public async Task GetHandHeldByIMEI_ShouldReturn_HandHeldWrapperDataView()
 {
    //Arrange
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var imei = "imeiNo";
    var handHeldWrapperDataViewMoq = fixture.Create<HandHeldWrapperDataView>();
    var returnResultMoq = ResponseResultHelper.SuccessfulResult(handHeldWrapperDataViewMoq.HandHeld, handHeldWrapperDataViewMoq.ResultSummary);
        mediatorMoq.Setup(x => x.Send( new GetHandHeldByIMEI(imei), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(handHeldWrapperDataViewMoq);

    //Act
    var actualResult = await sut.GetHandHeldByIMEI(imei);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(handHeldWrapperDataViewMoq, actualResult);
}
```

### Controller

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IAppAmbientState appAmbientState;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public HandheldController(
        IAppAmbientState ambientState,
        IMediator mediator
       )
    {
        appAmbientState = ambientState;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHandHeldByIMEI(string imei)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _mediator.Send(new GetHandHeldByIMEI(imei));

            var returnResult = ResponseResultHelper.SuccessfulResult(result.HandHeld, result.ResultSummary);

            var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnResult, Formatting.None);

             return Content(serializeObject, "application/json");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your mock is getting injected? How are you instantiating `sut`?

Comment: in test class; I am initiating  private readonly HandheldController sut; I have update code

Comment: @Toxic Did you not review my comment on the last post before you deleted it.

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use MOQ to mock dependencies.

Comment: The `GetHandHeldByIMEI` instance reference used in your setup and the actual instance used when exercising the test do not match so the mock will return null by default. Loosen the match by using `It.IsAny<GetHandHeldByIMEI>()` or `It.Is<>(...)` with a matching conditional

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks alot for the help that works for me